# VRT with overlapping images

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, transparency-opacity, vrt

I want to create a WMS of a VRT of eventually ~2500 GeoTIFFs. At the moment it's only five of them. This is my workflow:

1. Crop the (PDF) images in photoshop and save them as PNG.
2. Load the PNGs in QGIS, georeference them, save them as GeoTIFF.
3. Build a VRT of the images in QGIS
4. Upload the images and the VRT to my Geoserver and publish them as WMS.

This all works fine, but overlapping images show transpareny issues, as you can see in this picture:
[image: in_geoserver]

This is how both pictures look in QGIS and how they are supposed to look in the WMS as well (added red line to show the border between the images):
[image: in_qgis]

I added `<NODATA>0</NODATA>` to each `<ComplexSource>` in the VRT and also added 0 as Null Value in Geoserver:
[image]

Also I made sure to request the WMS as PNG, as JPG doesn't support transparency.

Whats my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

NODATA values are 255 for RGB channels and 0 for the alpha channel. This must be changed in the VRT, the changes in GeoServer don't have any effect at all.

The result is better, but not perfect:

[image]